# Conditional Query or Model in Cognos Reporting

Tags: reporting, cognos

I'm new to Cognos Reporting and I'm wondering there is a way to create models/queries that are conditional. For example:

```
"if x is not null then append this 'where line' to query"
```

Something like that, I'm still pretty new to Cognos so I may be using the wrong words.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter rows of a query subject,
Right click your query subject> Edit Defition> Filters Tab > Add a filter
In the expression definition box,

```
x is null or (x is not null and <where expression to append>)
```

If you want to apply the filter for a query item

```
case 
when x is not null and <where expression to append>
  then <some_query_item>
  else <some_query_item>
 end
```